# js: Using some custom jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit unusual case in my project. The jQuery is loaded under a namespace, like

```
var grp = {
    "jQuery": jQuery.noConflict(true)
};
```

So in my custom scripts I am doing:

```
(function($){...}(grp.jQuery);
```

The question I have is how to handle external jQuery plugins. E.g. I want to add autocomplete plugin, which depends on jQuery, and starts with

```
$(document).ready(function() { ....
```

And it looks like the only option to include them in source code like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/autocomplete_light/django_admin.js"></script>
```

would be to edit them all, which is not practical...

Comment: I can't understand what is your question.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

1. Move jQuery to where the plugins expect to find it (i.e. to a global)
2. Edit all the plugins to tell them where jQuery actually is

You could try writing a preprocessor that edits all the plugins for you at build time (this would probably be more work and more error prone than is worthwhile).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using the `$` variable name anywhere else,
maybe you can append it to the window on startup so it'll be available.

Something like:

```
(function(jQuery) {
    window.$ = jQuery;
}(grp.jQuery))
```